# Transform the field values pentaho(kattle) and store it in standard format in any table

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse

I want to transform the value of fields `name` and `Date` using `pentaho(kattle)` and store it in standard format in any table.

For example

> id,name,f_n,Date
>   1,j_vick,03-05-2015
>   2,jo_vick,04,08,2016
>   3,Arn_jonnn_vick,05,07,2017

Now I want to transform it using `pentaho(kattle)` IDE and store it in data base like below:

> id,name,Date
>   1,john_vick,03/05/2015
>   2,john_vick,04/08/2016
>   3,Arn_john_vick,05/07/2017

I don't want the transformation steps concern with extraction database   storage.

Comment: I could not figure out what's behind the last sentence. And: what's wrong with your shift keys? Broken? Both??

Comment: MySQL stores dates as YYYY-MM-DD ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)).  Storing as dd/mm/yyyy in a string column is not recommended.  If you want to convert `j_vick` and `jo_vick` to `John_Vick` you will need to maintain a lookup table within your database.  This will translate supplied value to approved value.  You will need a process for maintaining the list.

Answer (score 0):

The date format is just some clothing of a value. Just read it with Kettle and store it as is. The database will store it in its proper internal binary format anyway.

Unless, you have to store them explicitly as `varchar`. In that case, use the `Metadata` tab of the `Select Value` step. Define your column as `Date` and specify the format as `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`. It will be kept internally as a Date, and converted into a String with the selected format at the last moment.

You also seam to have an other problem: the day, month and year are in three columns. The easiest way is to use a `Modified Java Script Value` step, in which you define a new column `date = new Date(year, month, year)`, with type Date, and let Kettle handle with the format.

Maybe you have mixed input, in which case you can use a `Filter` or a `Swtich` step, based on weather you have something in the day and month column.

When that is done, you can make a job that runs the transformation on all the tables. You have an example in the `sample/jobs/process all tables` furnished with the Pentaho Data Integrator (aka Kettle).